How to create a new `branch` with `octokit`?
I'm using for the first time octokit (GitHub) and have been successfully doing some (tiny) things. However, I'm struggling to create a f****** new branch called featureA.
  try {
    await octokit.request('POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/refs', {
      owner: "my-orwner-name"
      repo: "my-repo-name"
      ref: 'refs/heads/featureA',
      sha: 'aa218f56b14c9653891f9e74264a383fa43fefbd', // dummy sha cuz branch does not exist
      headers: {'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28' }
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

The error:
HttpError: Object does not exist - https://docs.github.com/rest/git/refs#create-a-reference

Of course it doesn't exist: purpose is to create this branch...
Do you know what I'm missing? No clue on www.
Thanks.
